# Failure building Gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I tried to a create new project through Google maps activity but my android studio keeps through an exception whenever I try build the gradle. Please any solution colleagues. PC... haven't written any code yet.

Here is the gradle message ....

Error:error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
Error:error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Comment: what is your compile sdk version?

Comment: I used API 26... I dont actually know if thats what you really wanna know

Comment: In build.gradle (app: module) see compileSdk version. Change it to 28 android:attr/fontVariationSettings was added in api 28. See I have one answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61183638/error246-5-error-resource-androidattr-fontvariationsettings-not-found/61183698#61183698. Please see if this will help you.

Comment: Error:(23, 34) error: incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to SupportMapFragment

Comment: is your issue resolved?. If not please post the code where these errors are occurring..